# How to run python script on android for input and get output

Tags: android, python-3.x, copy-paste

I have a simple Python script which intakes a `string` and provides output as a `string`. I am totally a newcomer when it comes to coding or android app development. Please suggest a way where I can give input to my Python code on an Android phone.

the process is as follows.

1. I copy a `string` from my phone
2. I paste in that android terminal/ app
3. It returns with output `string` that I need to copy.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you can use pydroid, but i think there isnt what you want.
if you want to make an app that requires an input from the user and calls your function, you can use kivy + buildozer. kivy makes an application for windows or linux from python and buildozer copiles the application for android. but you need a machine or virtual machine with ubuntu, or maybe other distro, to use buildozer. just paste that on terminal.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Install Python pip
sudo apt-get install -y curl
sudo apt-get install -y python3-distutils
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
sudo python3 get-pip.py

# Dependencies with SDL2
# Install necessary system packages
sudo apt-get install -y \
    python-pip \
    build-essential \
    git \
    python \
    python3-dev \
    ffmpeg \
    libsdl2-dev \
    libsdl2-image-dev \
    libsdl2-mixer-dev \
    libsdl2-ttf-dev \
    libportmidi-dev \
    libswscale-dev \
    libavformat-dev \
    libavcodec-dev \
    zlib1g-dev

# Dependencies Kivy
sudo pip3 install cython

# Install Kivy
sudo pip3 install kivy

# Dependencies Buildozer
sudo apt install -y \
    build-essential \
    ccache \
    git \
    libncurses5:i386 \
    libstdc++6:i386 \
    libgtk2.0-0:i386 \
    libpangox-1.0-0:i386 \
    libpangoxft-1.0-0:i386 \
    libidn11:i386 \
    python2.7 \
    python2.7-dev \
    openjdk-8-jdk \
    unzip \
    zlib1g-dev \
    zlib1g:i386 \
    libltdl-dev \
    libffi-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    autoconf \
    autotools-dev
    cmake

# Install Buildozer
git clone https://github.com/kivy/buildozer.git
cd buildozer
sudo python3 setup.py install
```